# Date dialog box onDateSet function running twice

Tags: android, dialog

```
public String date_dialog()
         {
             final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
             mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
             mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

             DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                     new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                         @Override
                         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                 int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
                         {
                             date=dayOfMonth + "-"+ (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                            Toast.makeText(Mark_attendence.this,dayOfMonth + "-"+ (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                         }
                     }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
             dpd.show();

             return(date);
         }
```

This toast inside the ondateset function is running twice, when i click the done button on the dialog box,why is that?

Comment: From what I see, it shouldn't be doing that. You should print a debug in `onDateSet` to make sure `onDateSet` is actually being called once or twice.

Comment: Also on a side-note, I'm guessing from your code snippet what you're trying to do. If you're trying to call `date_dialog()` to prompt a `Dialog` so you can get the `date` string from what the user selected, your method right now will return the moment the dialog shows. You can only capture the actual selected `date` in the callback `onDateSet`.